# Aggregate query with min

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

Having a `product_stock` table with following structure:

```
product_id
warehouse_id
stock
price
```

Which has bunch of records (same product can be in different warehouses):

```
1, 1, 0, 500
1, 2, 5, 505
1, 3, 7, 508
2, 1, 0, 400
2, 2, 0, 404
```

Now, for every `product_id`, I want to select cheapest one in stock and if product is not in stock anymore, select price and warehouse as NULL - basically, the result should be:

```
1, 2, 5, 505
2, NULL, 0, NULL
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d9ad67/2).

**[Update]:** Almost nailed it (now need to figure out how to select appropriate warehouse):

```
select product_id, min(price) from (
    select product_id,
        CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else warehouse_id end,
        CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else price end from stock
) AS f group by product_id;
```

Returning (still need to figure out the `warehouse_id`):

```
product_id  min
1   505
2   (null)
```

**[Update 2]:** I was able to get the `warehouse_id`, but this query kills the row without price:

```
SELECT stock.product_id, stock.warehouse_id, stock.price FROM (
    SELECT product_id, min(price) as price FROM (
        SELECT product_id,
          CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else warehouse_id end,
          CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else price end
        FROM stock
    ) AS f GROUP by product_id
) AS ff JOIN
stock on stock.product_id=ff.product_id and stock.price = ff.price;
```

Result:

```
product_id  warehouse_id    price
1   2   505
```

Comment: I tried various if-else approaches, though I guess I actually need to do a self-referencing join.

Comment: Your approach is ok. What are you going to do about duplicate min-prices? This will get you a bit further: select * from (
select product_id, min(price) as price from (
    select product_id,
        CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else warehouse_id end,
        CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else price end
) AS f from product_stock group by product_id) min_prices
join product_stock stock on stock.price=min_prices.price
and stock.product_id=min_prices.product_id
;

Comment: Which version of Postgres do you use?

Comment: @ypercube: Postgres 9.3+

Comment: 9.3+? Is that 9.3 or 9.4? And table definition: it is always much better to post the actual table definition (what you get with `\d tbl` in psql) where we can see exact data types, NULL clause, constraints, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be much simpler, yet, with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
       product_id
     , CASE WHEN stock = 0 THEN NULL ELSE warehouse_id END AS warehouse_id
     , stock
     , CASE WHEN stock = 0 THEN NULL ELSE price END AS price
FROM   product_stock
ORDER  BY product_id, (stock = 0), price;
```

Assuming `stock` to be `NOT NULL`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fbfe4/5)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Postgres has a proper `boolean` type and one can `ORDER BY` any boolean expression. `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE` sorts before `NULL`. So rows with `(stock = 0)` sort behind rows with any other value for `stock` - except NULL, which would sort last.

Comment: @plaes: No, not at all. `(stock = 0)` only sorts numbers before `0` and `NULL`. I.e. it leaves numbers *unsorted* otherwise, so that sorting by `price` in the example above actually works.

Comment: Wonderful - PostgreSQL docs should really have an example of such `ORDER BY` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Two similar versions. One:

```
-- query 1 --
WITH a AS
  ( SELECT 
        product_id, warehouse_id, stock, price,
        MIN(CASE WHEN stock > 0 THEN price END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)
          AS min_price,
        MIN(CASE WHEN stock = 0 THEN price END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)
          AS min_non_stock_price
    FROM stock
  )  
SELECT product_id, 
       CASE WHEN stock > 0 THEN warehouse_id END AS warehouse_id, 
       stock, 
       CASE WHEN stock > 0 THEN price END AS price
FROM a 
WHERE stock > 0         AND price = min_price
   OR min_price IS NULL AND price = min_non_stock_price ;
```

and two:

```
-- query 2 --
WITH a AS
  ( SELECT 
        product_id, warehouse_id, stock, price,
        MIN(CASE WHEN stock > 0 THEN price END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)
          AS min_price
    FROM stock
  )  
SELECT product_id, warehouse_id, stock, price
FROM a 
WHERE price = min_price 

UNION ALL

SELECT product_id, NULL, 0, NULL
FROM a 
WHERE min_price IS NULL
GROUP BY product_id ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/544bb/3).

Comment: Wow! :) (after fixing following typo: `s/product_stock/stock`)

Comment: Your question starts with: *"Having a `product_stock` table ..."*

Comment: Ah.. indeed, in my sqlfiddle that I created later, I had simply `stock`.

Comment: And my `price` in the external query should have a `CASE` as well, to show `NULL` and not the price from the warehouse with 0 stock.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tried with `CTE-s`:

```
WITH min_prices AS (
  SELECT product_id, min(price) price FROM (
    SELECT product_id,
      CASE WHEN stock = 0 then NULL else price end
    FROM stock) as _ GROUP BY product_id
), existing_stock AS (
  SELECT product_id, warehouse_id, price FROM stock WHERE stock > 0
)
SELECT min_prices.product_id,
       existing_stock.warehouse_id,
       min_prices.price FROM min_prices
LEFT JOIN existing_stock ON
    min_prices.product_id = existing_stock.product_id AND
    min_prices.price = existing_stock.price;
```

Resulting in win :)

```
product_id  warehouse_id    price
1   2   505
2   (null)  (null)
```

Execution plan doesn't look that impressive, though:

```
Hash Join  (cost=49.97..114.58 rows=3 width=12)
  Hash Cond: ((stock.product_id = min_prices.product_id) AND (stock.price = min_prices.price))
CTE min_prices
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=40.97..42.97 rows=200 width=12)
    ->  Seq Scan on stock stock_1  (cost=0.00..27.70 rows=1770 width=12)
    ->  Seq Scan on stock  (cost=0.00..32.12 rows=590 width=12)
Filter: (stock > 0)
    ->  Hash  (cost=4.00..4.00 rows=200 width=8)
    ->  CTE Scan on min_prices  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=200 width=8)
```